# Goto line number , and edit a string there in file using C++

Tags: c++, file, file-io

I am trying to make a function which gets two parameters one Line_number and 2nd a string. This function will open a File Pre-Populated and skip till Line "Line_number" is reached , get that line and post some other line instead.But it does not work. I have seen other solutions but cant find right solution. Kindly help me with it.

```
   fstream Inoutput_file;
   void BackPatch(int GotoLineNo, string LineNo)
   {

     for (int i = 1; i <= GotoLineNo; i++)
     {
        char* str = new char[20];
         Inoutput_file.getline(str, 20, '\n');
        if (i == LineNo-1)
        {
            Inoutput_file.seekp(Inoutput_file.tellg());
            Inoutput_file.getline(str, 20, '\n');
            cout << str << endl;                //prints the correct line
            Inoutput_file << "Goto " + str <<endl;  //donot work
            cout << "Goto " + str<<endl;      // Prints correct line
        }

  }
  Inoutput_file.seekp(0);
  Inoutput_file.seekg(0);
}
```

In main:

```
  Inoutput_file.open("example.txt");
  BackPatch(3,"Print this to Line 3 instead");
  Inoutput_file.close();
```

I would Also Like to Mention here that I have opened same File with different instance of "ifstream" to work for rest of my program.

Comment: Could you be more specific than "it does not work"?

Comment: Thats what I want to figure out.. the line
 Inoutput_file << "Goto "+ str <<endl; 
is not working..

Comment: I want to mention here that I have opened same file with different instance of "ifstream" to use for rest of program.

Comment: "It doesn't work" and "is not working" don't provide any useful information to anyone except yourself. There are countless more ways a program can *not work* than there are ways it can work. Do you have any concrete information about how your actual output differs from your expected output?

Comment: Please post a working example of your code. Also write how you code should work, and what you get instead. There is also another big problem in your code: Variable and function names should start with a lower case letter. Also use camel case for the naming instead of underscores.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fstream Inoutput_file;
   void BackPatch(int GotoLineNo, string LineNo)
   {

```
 for (int i = 1; i <= GotoLineNo; i++)
 {
    char* str = new char[20];
     Inoutput_file.getline(str, 20, '\n');
    if (i == LineNo-1)
    {
        Inoutput_file.seekp(Inoutput_file.tellg());
        Inoutput_file.getline(str, 20, '\n');
        cout << str << endl;                //prints the correct line
        Inoutput_file << "Goto " + str <<endl;  //Now it will work fine
        cout << "Goto " + str<<endl;      // Prints correct line
    }
```

}